# Accesing the Load Balancer in Azure?

Tags: windows, azure, dns, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

I need to set up a DNS server on azure and set an MX Record pointing to a third party smtp server.

In the worker/web role implementations in azure, each has a load balancer which is the public IP of my whole implementation. I need to access that load balancer and set up the MX Record in there since its IP is to where all mail.mydns.com requests will go.

How can I do this? I see no options in the configuraiton manager.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

You don't get access to Azure's DNS records. You can change your MX record on the website where you bought your domain name.